# Multiple .bashrc.save in my ~/home/user/

Tags: linux, debian, bashrc

I noticed that in my home folder I have multiple .bashrc.save files. Why the system save them? It is normal or I have to disable something?

Specifically I have

> .bashrc
>
> .bashrc.save
>
> .bashrc.save1
>
> .bashrc.save2
>
> .bashrc.save3
>
> .bashrc.save4
>
> .bashrc.save5

Comment: Did you use some editor to edit the contents of `.bashrc`? The editor might have an automatic backup feature.

Comment: Yes I used nano to edit .bashrc

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nano that generated this files, look at this from GNU Nano website:

In some cases nano will try to dump the buffer into an emergency file. This will happen mainly if nano receives a SIGHUP or SIGTERM or runs out of memory. **It will write the buffer into a file named nano.save if the buffer didn’t have a name already, or will add a ".save" suffix to the current filename. If an emergency file with that name already exists in the current directory, it will add ".save" plus a number (e.g. ".save.1") to the current filename in order to make it unique**. In multibuffer mode, nano will write all the open buffers to their respective emergency files.

Link: http://www.nano-editor.org/dist/v2.2/nano.1.html

Or in your shell:

```
$ man nano
```

Comment: Glad I could help you!
Help me out by marking my response as useful with, up, up, up! :D